# How to restrict page access to logged-in users?

Tags: php, functions

Certain pages on a client site are confidential and I need to restrict access to logged in users. I have looked at various membership plugins but they are overkill for my very basic and specific needs.

I found this snippet which I tested in functions.php

```
function my_force_login() {
global $post;

if (!is_single()) return;

$ids = array(188); // array of post IDs that force login to read

if (in_array((int)$post->ID, $ids) && !is_user_logged_in()) {
auth_redirect();
}
}
```

When I tested it this code, it restricted a particular blog post EXACTLY how I want it. (the key here is that if the user clicks on a link to a restricted page but is not logged in, they are redirected to a login page, but after they complete login, they should be redirected back to the EXACT original page)

Now I need to modify that code so it will do the following:

Restrict all the pages with a particular parent.

Is that possible? How should the code be modified to achieve this outcome?

Thanks

Comment: [This worked for me](https://pastebin.com/xfNfb385), so I thought you might want to try it.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
function my_force_login() {
  global $post;

  if (!is_single()) return;

  $restricted_parent_id = 1 // Whatever id you are targeting.

  if ($post->post_parent == $restricted_parent_id && !is_user_logged_in()) {
    auth_redirect();
  }
}
```

More info on `post_parent` and other conditional tags here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: This solution caused php errors but it was helpful in that it helped me take this process a step further. I'm now successfully restricting a page. but I still haven't figured out how to restrict all pages with a particular parent.